# What is the origin of the Roman hand-laying ritual which the word "assert" traces back to?

Tags: ancient-rome, slavery, etymology, latin-language

According to the OED 2nd edition (and [OED 1913](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.99992/page/n543/mode/2up), [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dassero2), and [Gaffiot](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/adsero)) the earliest known attestation of the word *assert* is a Roman hand-laying ritual:

> **assert**, v.
> (əˈsɜːt)[f. L. *assert-* ppl. stem of *as-serĕre* (f. *ad* to + *serĕre* to join, put) to put one's hand on the head of a slave, either to set him free or claim him for servitude, *hence*, to set free, protect, defend; to appropriate, claim; to affirm, declare, state. Cf. also med.L. *assertāre* (freq. of *asserĕre*) to affirm.]

I wonder:
**Have historians researched this stated Roman hand-laying ritual and its origins? And, do we know if *assert* was used before that in a more literal meaning?**

Comment: @LangLangC I rewrote. I left the OED quote you kindly provided and linked to L&S, since I prefer the OED summary.

Comment: I suspect this is as unanswerable as the origin of the handshake, but it's an interesting question given the related origin of "[manumission](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manumission)".

Comment: On a side-note: In the newly released mammoth-project TLL, I found an entry on adsero (2nd lemma). Somebody more versed in Latin than me, maybe can decipher if there are any new interesting references here: https://publikationen.badw.de/de/thesaurus/lemmata#12824

Comment: Perusal of literature seems to indicate historians are struggling to understand the exact process based on scant literary evidence. Tristan Husby, "Recognizing Freedom: Manumission in the Roman Republic", Ph.D. thesis, CUNY, 2017: "...  it is possible that the Romans used elements from the procedure of *adsertio libertatis* when they created the legal process of manumission, most especially the role of the *adsertor*. Since slaves, ... , could not represent themselves in the Roman court, the *adsertor* was the person who advocated on behalf of the person who claimed to be enslaved wrongfully."